# Trying to exclude posts from a category on the home page

Tags: php, categories, query

I've tried the code below to grab the cat ID for one of my categories (watch-isatv) and exclude all of the posts in that category. However, the posts are not being excluded. What is wrong with the code?

```
function excludeCat($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $catid = get_cat_ID('watch-isatv');
        $query->set('cat', '-'.$catid);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, `pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter, and you don't need to return anything and `$query` is passed in by reference, but that code should nonetheless work. Cleaned up it would be:

```
function excludeCat($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home ) {
        $catid = get_cat_ID('watch-isatv');
        $query->set('cat', '-'.$catid);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

There are several potential points of failure though.

1. You are adding the filter after the main query has run. You must add
   that filter before the main query. `functions.php` should work but
   adding that code in your other theme template files, like
   `archive.php` or `home.php` won't. The main query has already executed.
2. `$query->is_home` isn't what you expect or need it to be. Add
   `var_dump($query->is_home);` to your code and load your page(s).
   Make sure it is `true` where you need it to be and `false`
   otherwise.
3. The slug, not the human readable name, used with `get_cat_ID()` is
   incorrect.

I'd put my money on #1 being the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your child themes functions file & replace 007 with the I.D for the category of posts you want to exclude from the home page.

```
function wpsites_exclude_category_home( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-007' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_exclude_category_home' );
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this beforehand, but I want to be able to use the slug instead of the ID. Would it be possible to use your code with the slug?

Comment: You might find the answer here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts